# Edit Categories On Entry With Channel Forms

Tags: safecracker

Is it possible to edit categories against an entry using ExpressionEngine Channel Forms?

The **{selected}** variable doesn't seem to be getting set, so it's always resetting back to the first category in the select drop down.

```
<select name="category[]" id="categories">
   {exp:channel:categories category_group="3"}
   <option value="{category_id}" {selected}>{category_name}</option>
   {/exp:channel:categories}
</select>
```

I'm using EE2.9.0, and no upgrading is not an option. Also, yes I've used Channel Forms before and it's all working aside from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation would lead me to suggest using the native `{category_menu}` variable pair.

http://ee2docs.com/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#categories

This is the example from the docs:

```
{category_menu}
    <label for="categories">Categories</label>
    <select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4" multiple="multiple">
        {select_options}
    </select>
{/category_menu}
```

That *should* do it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. How did I miss that? Thank you.

Comment: It happens! I just happen to be a master doc scanner :p glad it worked though!